# Cannot find name `data`, but it's defined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following error: "Cannot find name 'data'.", but I *have* defined it.

```
const initialState = () => {
  try {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem('auth');
  } catch (e) {
    const data = null;
  }

  if (!data) {
    return {
      matrixIsAuthenticated: false,
      matrixUserId: null,
      matrixAccessToken: null,
    };
  } else {
    return data;
  }
};
```

Comment: because data is defined in the block scope of the try and the catch. It is not available outside the `{}`.

Comment: unsure why you think you need the try catch. Do you think `localStorage` is going to throw an error? I am also guessing your code needs to parse the string into an object. since you returns are totally different when data has no data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define `data` variable outside `try` block first with `let` and give it value inside `try` only after that.

Comment: OP actually doesn't need the try/catch at all

Comment: For sure, but for learning purposes, I think it's okay. When you start learning programming you should just get your hands dirty and not think much about the best ways of dealing with problems. You should not be afraid of trying things.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to understand the scope of a block of code. Once you define a  variable inside the try block it cannot be accessed outside of it. similar case for the catch also.

Solution 01: Define it outside of the `try-catch` block. Also, use `let` since `const` cannot assign a value twice.

Solution 02: move the whole code into the `try-catch` block.